# Javascript only works in IE Compat Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Please see the below javascript. This works in all other browsers apart from IE. In IE Compat mode must be enabled for it to work. Any idea why? I believe its something to do with the indexOf.

```
    var styles = iDoc.find("head style[id$='ReportControl_styles']").html();
            if ((styles == undefined) || (styles == '')) {
                iDoc.find('head script').each(function () {
                    var cnt = $(this).html(); 
                    var p1 = cnt.indexOf('ReportStyles":"');
                    if (p1 > 0) {
                        p1 += 15;
                        var p2 = cnt.indexOf('"', p1);
                        styles = cnt.substr(p1, p2 - p1);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (styles == '') { alert("Cannot generate styles, Displaying without styles.."); }
            styles = '<style type="text/css">' + styles + "</style>";
```

Comment: Please open the developer console and look for any errors.

Comment: use this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FindexOf) it may be helpful for you.

Comment: What IE version are you using? IE versions < 9 don't have indexOf

Comment: What is `iDoc`? What are the errors in the console? What does not work exactly?

Comment: Hi, No Errors. Browser is IE10. So I'm guessing IE10 doesn't support indexOf?

Comment: Need more info: Firstly, *which* compat mode are you using? How are you enabling it? Second: What are the exact symptoms of it not working? Does it throw errors, stop unexpectedly, or simply bypass the loop altogether? Finally, some pointers: `indexOf` certainly *is* supported by IE10. It is not supported in IE8 or earlier for arrays, but is supported in all versions for strings, which is what you're using it for. Also, please note that the `id` attribute is not strictly valid for `style` elements; this is my guess as to the real reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I have removed the doctype from the page and also added  and all is working fine.